# GCM push notification in Android

Tags: android

I am using Google sample project to push notification, I have build and deployed both client and server application successfully and I am able to register device on server side, when i am trying to send notification, it shows that message has been pushed but i am not notified on device or emulator.

Client application is compiled and deployed with IDE eclipse and Sample Server application is build by ANT builder and deployed in Tomcat 7.

I am using Android 4.2 Google API emulator and devices with gmail configuration.

Comment: show your code(both server and client side)

Comment: if you have SDK installed and that is updated with google Extras then follow this http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html and you eill find Client and server code

Comment: I am using my App Access code and sender id

Comment: I have been solve this problem and using the same client server code but making build of server code using Ant builder and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

In this article I will try to explain how we can integrate a push notification service for Android using ASP.NET and C#. We all know that mobile applications are booming the market trend. Some custom mobile applications use the push notification service to give updates to application users. Here I will explain how we can use Google’s GCM push notification service.

Class file "AndroidGCMPushNotification.cs"

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Net.Security;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;


public class AndroidGCMPushNotification
{
    public AndroidGCMPushNotification()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public string SendNotification(string deviceId, string message)
    {
        string GoogleAppID = "google application id";        
        var SENDER_ID = "9999999999";
        var value = message;
        WebRequest tRequest;
        tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "®istration_id=" + deviceId + "";
        Console.WriteLine(postData);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();


        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
        return sResponseFromServer;
    }
}
```

You can call SendNotification function by passing device Id and Message.

```
AndroidGCMPushNotification apnGCM = new AndroidGCMPushNotification();

string strResponse =
apnGCM.SendNotification("123123xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"Test Push Notification message ");
```

Answer (score 0):

To send GCM push you dont really require to have a third party server in berween.
Thats the best part of GCM over C2DM.

```
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
     httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "key=" + GCM_AUTH_KEY);
     httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

     try {

        String reqBody = DATA_YOU_WANNA_SEND_INJSON_FORMAT;

        BasicHttpEntity e = new BasicHttpEntity();

        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(reqBody.getBytes());
        e.setContent(is);
        httppost.setEntity(e);
        Log.d("@@ Data being sent via push : " + reqBody);

        return httpclient.execute(httppost);
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(e.getMessage());
     } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(e.getMessage());
     }
```

By this method you can send the push messages.

If you talk about why the demo app is not sending push, then I also tried it when I was implementing I faced the same issue.

But using this approach you can always send the GCM, only thing is your device must be registered.

Also, result can be seen via:

int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.d("@@ response status code :: " + statusCode);

```
        if (statusCode == 200) {
           callback.onSuccess();
        } else {
           String reason = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
           Log.d("@@ response reason phrase :: " + reason);
           callback.onFailure(reason);
        }
        Log.d("@@ complete response object : " + EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

Comment: hi I have done GCM and showing multiple notifications, now i need to put all notifications coming from same API access key should be in same group, is it possible?

Comment: now the question is different. but can be done. I am not sure if while receiving the Push message info like access key is provided or not, but you can always send it in the data of message also, and after parsing on the receiver's end you can definitely group the notifications as you like

Answer (score -1):

Check your Android emulator is using Google APIs and you have Google Play services extra installed.

**Install Google Play services:**
[image]

**Select Google APIs for Android emulator target:**
[image]